# Switch account on eclipse

Tags: codenameone

Until now I was using my free personnal account to develop with Codename one. I couldn't send my builds anymore because I have reached the 1MB limit. Now my compagny bought a basic subscription and I would like to use it but I can't: when I send my build the server, it tries to send it with my personnal account. I tried to solve that issue downloading a new eclipse version but it doesn't work.

How can I sent my builds using my new basic account ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by changing the password of your free account [here](https://www.codenameone.com/build-server.html#account-tab), which will prompt you for new login details when you send a build... then you can enter your basic account details when prompted.

**Note:** Codename One may suspend your basic account if they discover it's been used by multiple users within your company. They have one account one user policy, so don't abuse it. The only account that **MAY** be shared by multiple developers within a single company is an [Enterprise account](https://www.codenameone.com/build-server.html#subscription-tab).

Comment: Thanks ;-)
FYI an enterprise account can't be shared either. They are all per developer seat. We used to have a corporate option but that was pretty different.

Comment: By the way, I will propose that you should have pricing plan that will cover a team of developers with some sort flag to limit maximum number seat.

Comment: I agree, we need team discounts in the self serve subscription level. We do have such discounts when working with invoicing/SWIFT payment. The main reason these (and some other features) don't exist is that a lot of our backend infrastructure still relies on app engine despite repeated attempts at moving away. It's hard for us to stop all other development for a month or more just to switch infrastructure and doing extra work on app engine just digs us in deeper. That's one of the reasons we don't have other billing methods (besides paypal).